# How do I split a sentence by a specific word with php?

Tags: php

How can I split a sentence or string into two different parts?

```
$string = "First Name Last Name on 4/30/13";
$string = "First Name on 4/28/13";
$string = "First Name Last Name";
```

how do I extract the name, and the date into two different variables? The string changes. It sometimes has on Date, and sometimes doesn't.

Comment: first idea: explode on space, if 3rd word is on, that's one format if its 2nd that's another if its not there that's the third

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would be to use [`explode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), perhaps like this:

```
 list($name, $date) = array_pad(explode(' on ', $string), 2, null);
```

This will assign the name to `$name` and the date to `$date`; if there is no date, `$date` will be `null`.

Be mindful of the fact that `explode` is quite dumb and will happily break up the name if it contains the string `' on '`. In this case this is highly unlikely because I have included the surrounding spaces in the string, but the more naive explode on `'on'` would easily backfire with a name like "Marion Jones".

For more advanced matching you would have to move up to [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: " on " could be a last name

Comment: @Dagon: Well, names can be anything really. For industrial-strength parsing you 'd have to specifically target just the date and consider everything "not date" as the name.

Comment: yup, i was just pointing it out, i have no solution for it :-) http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you need to use regular expressions.

Check the documentation for [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, here is an example of each one

```
<?php
$string = "First Name Last Name on 4/30/13";
print_r(explode(" on ", $string));

$string = "First Name on 4/28/13";
print_r(explode(" on ", $string));

$string = "First Name Last Name";
print_r(explode(" on ", $string));
```

And here is the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => First Name Last Name 
    [1] => 4/30/13
)
Array
(
    [0] => First Name 
    [1] => 4/28/13
)
Array
(
    [0] => First Name Last Name
)
```